# Jquery UI (Sortable, Draggable and Droppable): drop event incorrectly triggered when dragging a draggable over a droppable onto a sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

Drop event incorrectly triggered when dragging a draggable over a droppable onto a sortable.

JS:

```
$('.sortable-fx').sortable();
$('.droppable-fx').droppable({
    drop:function(event,ui){
        var tpl = '<div class="msg-fx">Drop Event Triggered</div>';
        $(".console-fx").append(tpl);
    }
});
$('.draggable-fx').draggable({
    connectToSortable:'.sortable-fx',
    helper:'clone'
});
```

Please click to see the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/atulkushwah/t5pyb/15/

Note: There are some work-around using mouse-down-up but that will not work into IE browser due to drop trigger first then mouse-up will fire.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Same here, what browser are you testing on ? I'm on chrome

Comment: Its for all browsers(FF, Chrome & IE10), Try to reproduce like start dragging a draggable and quick move (shaking mouse fast) 3-4 times over sortable to droppable and you could see a drop event get fired without even drop the draggable.

Comment: @AtulKushwah seems like a bug to me. Please update the question with steps to reproduce and try reporting a [bug here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com) referring this question.

Comment: @TilwinJoy Already a bug registered here [link](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6259) and unfortunately its still open. So I'm seeking some help/work-around here till not originally resolved by JQueryUI